# CodeIgniter empty $_FILES in another function

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

The flow of my multi-part form is basically **Answer form -> Preview form -> Upload to database**

Right now I upload my files in the Preview step since the `POST` data is fresh from the actual form. My problem is to access `$_FILES` once in the Upload to database function because `var_dump($_FILES)` returns `array(0) {}` once inside `upload_to_database()`.

**I want to do the file upload in the `upload_to_database()` function and not in the Preview step.**

I thought of actually making hidden `input[type=file]` in the Preview step just so that my `upload_to_database()` will receive `$_FILES`, but this is not possible due to security reasons.

How can I get a full and persistent `$_FILES` from Preview to `upload_to_database()`?

Comment: Use a Tab Method for the steps(answer,preview,upload) that way you don't need to loose any data, simply print the variables/input values, and for the $_FILES array, you could post that into an iframe on the preview tab

Answer (score 0):

May be you can put `$_FILES` in `$_SESSION` in "Preview step" and get it in "Upload step"

Comment: I think it will not be possible once the data is > 4kb which is the limit for CI Sessions.

Comment: Save files in "Preview step" in temporary directory (it must be cleared every day by cron) and save files normaly in "Upload step".

Answer (score 0):

You could store the file on the server and then pass the file's location in $_SESSION. Then just set up a cron job to do housekeeping and remove any files that have sat for more than whatever seems a reasonable amount of time.